# Uniquely named log file with Timestamp using logback for my SpringBoot application

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback

Im trying to create a log file for my application using logback, the file is generated on the path i wrote when i use these configurations in my application.yml

```
logging:
  file:
    path: C:\Users\MICRO\Documents\relatorios-web.log
    level:
      root: ERROR
      org.springframework.web: ERROR
      com.demo: DEBUG
      org.hibernate: ERROR
```

but it comes with a generic "spring.txt" name, when i want to create one with the timestamp from when  it was generated, i tried creating a logback file but it didnt do anything so i don't know where i'm missing in my configuration

```
<configuration>

    <!-- Insert the current time formatted as "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss" under
         the key "bySecond" into the logger context. This value will be
         available to all subsequent configuration elements. -->
    <timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"
               timeReference="contextBirth"/>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <!-- use the previously created timestamp to create a uniquely
             named log file -->
        <file>relatorios-parametro-${bySecond}.txt</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%logger{35} -%kvp- %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

and here's my main

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GerenciamentoModuloApplication {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GerenciamentoModuloApplication.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GerenciamentoModuloApplication.class, args);
        log.info("rodando relatorio-parametro-Api");
    }
```

I tried setting a name by the application.yml

```
logging:
  file:
    name: relatorios.parametro
    path: C:\Users\MICRO\Documents\relatorios-web.log
    level:
      root: ERROR
      org.springframework.web: ERROR
      com.demo: DEBUG
      org.hibernate: ERROR
```

but it created inside the project, when i want this specific path and i didnt supported putting a timestamp in the name

my pom:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <groupId>modulo-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>gerenciamento-modulo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gerenciamento-modulo</name>
    <description>api de gerenciamento de modulo </description>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version> <!-- Sonar -->
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <net.sf.jasperreports.version>6.20.0</net.sf.jasperreports.version>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependencia do log -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependencias do logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependencia do encoder do logstash para o logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>${net.sf.jasperreports.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>${net.sf.jasperreports.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.20</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>                     -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring                  </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wait>1000</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>180</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-and-report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report-aggregate</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/../target/site/jacoco-aggregate</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: I've tried your logback.xml and got such exception: There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [kvp]. However, log file was created in the root of a project. Try to replace pattern e.g. `<pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>`. In addition, can u show your pom/gradle and properties?

Comment: my pom is posted